# pyinstaller: Command not found

Tags: python, raspbian-jessie

I have installed pyinstaller using pip3. In my home/pi folder, i have a python file (testProg.py)
I tried to create the executable using pyinstaller.

```
pyinstaller --onefile testProg.py
```

But I am getting the following error

```
pyinstaller: command not found
```

Is it a directory problem? any help, please

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 install pyinstaller
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.6)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pyinstaller) (40.8.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder where it was installed is probably not in your path.

It's easiest to install it in a virtual environment:

```sh
python3 -m venv pyinstaller-venv
source ./pyinstaller-venv/bin/activate
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller -v
```

You'll be able to use pyinstaller whenever you activate the virtual environment.

---

Alternatively, add the right folder to your path. It seems like you have installed Python in `~/.local`, so make sure that `~/.local/bin` is in your path:

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

You can make it permanent by adding the `export ...` command to your `~/.profile` file.

If that's not the right path, you can search for `pyinstaller` using the `find` command:

```sh
find ~ -name pyinstaller -type f
```

Comment: I checked my .profile file.

Comment: @sunny_old_days please explain exactly what you did. I proposed three possible solutions.

Comment: 1 I tried `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH" ` and worked fine. But my program is a GUI application and there is a DateEntry Widget. Somehow it doesn't work after creating executable using pyinstaller. If I remove the DateEntry widget, everything works fine.

Comment: @sunny_old_days that sounds like a different problem.